# Automatically fill rows from another sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook that I'm using to keep track of product that I've ordered. At the moment, it has 2 sheets - one is an inventory list of each item organized in rows with all the particulars (product ID, min/max quantities, description, price etc) in each column. On the second sheet, I keep track of when items have been ordered along with the purchase order numbers. Currently, I copy the row of the item I'm ordering from the inventory sheet and paste it on the second sheet with the purchase order number, date and quantity ordered. I keep this as a running list that I keep adding to so that I can see trends and order history. Is there a way to, on the second sheet, type in the product ID, hit enter and have it populate the row with the info of the same product ID from the inventory sheet? It would save a huge amount of time to eliminate the copy and paste since there are thousands of product IDs and their info.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. We are not a code-writing service. While we're happy to help answer specific questions, we at least ask that you have studied, tried, learned, and maybe come up against something you cannot then understand. So, if you've already tried something, please edit your question to reflect this. If you haven't, please do so.

Answer (score 2):

For that size of a collection, maybe you should look into using Access, or some other database solution. Still, here goes.

Use the VLOOKUP function in Excel. As an example:

Sheet1 has this layout

```
     |     A      |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
1    | Product ID | Max Q | Min Q | Desc. | Price | 
2    |  ######### |   ### |    ## | xxxxx | 34.29 |
...
2359 |  ######### |   ### |    ## | xxxxx | 54.28 |
```

Sheet2 has this layout

```
     |     A     |     B     |    C    |     D     |     E      |   F   |   G   |
1    |Order date | Recv Date | Order Q | P.O. Num. | Product ID | Desc. | Price |
2    |           |           |         |           |            |       |       |
```

In Sheet2 cell E2 you enter the Product ID that matches some ID in Sheet1 column A.
In Sheet2 cell F2 you enter the formula `=VLOOKUP(E2,Sheet1!$A$2:$E$2359,4,TRUE)` and in G2 you enter the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$H$2359,5,TRUE)`. The range references are absoluted `$` so they don't change as the formula is copied down the page, and the 3rd parameter is the column "inside" the range that has the value you want. If, for example, Sheet1 started  in column H, then the range would change to `Sheet1!$H$2:$L$2` but the 4 for Desc. and the 5 for Price would *not* change. You can get around having to update the range in the formulas every time you add a product by using a named range, check Excel's help for that. The product ID column needs to be sorted for best effect based on your reported dataset size, though not required by VLOOKUP, and you will have to copy the formulas from row 2 down as far as you think you need them (however many thousand rows that might be.) If the sheets have names then place them inside single quotes, like `=VLOOKUP(E2,'Inventory List'!$A$2:$E$2359,4,TRUE)`. In the formula, the 1st argument `E2` is the cell to match against, the 2nd argument `Sheet1!$A$1:$H$2359` is the range to look in - the search is **only** done in the *first* column, the 3rd argument is the column in the range for the data to return, and the 4th argument `TRUE` forces an exact match.

Seriously.. consider migrating such a large dataset to a database. It'll mean more work now, but a lot better in the long run, including the ability to spot trends easier with less hassle.

Comment: Thanks Gypsy Spellweaver, I'll try it in the morning when I get back to work. The only reason in using a spreadsheet is because the inventory software that we use is a proprietary database of some sort that doesn't have the ability to track the history of each time I order any items to re-supply the inventory - I've asked the company that designed it and they said no. So, I export the list of materials to this spreadsheet every few days so that I can do it manually. If I could export the list into a separate access database and do what I want, the even better.

Comment: I am, by no means, an expert in Access, or MS-Office in general, but if you can export the data to Excel, you can probably either import it into Access the same was, or use Excel as a filter. Do take time before-hand to plan the database, based on the functionality you need, or can imagine you might need. Doing it right the first time is a lot easier than changing it later. Also, if you do migrate, run both systems in parallel to test the new system for a while (depending on the level of activity at least a month, maybe more) until you're sure all functions work as expected.